# How to use YUI's

Tags: jquery, yui

I experienced with JQuery and new to YUI.

I'm looking for YUI's equivalent of the JQuery "$(document).ready".

I found "onDOMReady". If I have a .JS document with a large number of functions, what is the right way to wrap them all in "onDOMReady"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(function(){

    YAHOO.myModule.init();
    YAHOO.myOtherModule.init();

    });
```

I usually do something like the above. Otherwise you can do things like the following if you just need a specific element to be present

```
YAHOO.util.Event.onAvailable('required-element', YAHOO.myModule.init);
```

Comment: With JQuery, you can add any chunk of code within document.ready. It seems with YUI that you have to use YUI modules. How can I easily wrap a block of functions into a module in order to use onDOMREADY?

Comment: You can use any code within onDOMReady, just like in jquery. It's just a callback that gets executed at the specified time.

Answer (score 14):

In YUI3 you can do this (see below), but it's not really necessary, if you put the link to the YUI JS at the bottom of the html body tag, as recommended.

```
YUI().use('node', function(Y) {
      Y.on("domready", function(){
        console.log('dom is ready');
        // your code
      }); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
YUI().use('event', function (Y) {
 var button = Y.one("#readygo");
 var buttonname= this.get('value'); 
 alert(buttonname);
}
</script>


<input type="button" name="button" id="readygo" value="Click">
```

Refer Here: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/